# Spring Batch Admin - missing resources

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I'm using the latest Spring Batch Admin (1.3.0.RELEASE) and am including the 'admin-manager' and 'admin-resources' in my WAR artifact pom file.

```
<dependencies>
        ....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.admin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-resources</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.admin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The issue i'm having is that the css and image resources are never correctly linked, so my admin home page looks like this. Any advise on how i can configure my context to include these resources correctly?

[image: Spring Batch Admin without resources]

Answer (score 1):

We are having the same issue. Could anyone from the spring batch team be able to help ? Looks like somehow the admin resources bundle is not getting loaded correctly.